# Calculate $\int_{\gamma} \frac{z^2}{\sin(z^3)} dz $ where $\gamma=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|=\frac{3}{2}\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration, laurent-series

Calculate $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{z^2}{\sin(z^3)} dz $$ where $\gamma=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|=\frac{3}{2}\}$

Can I use the Laurent expansion?

Comment: Do you know the residue theorem?

Comment: Yes, I got a result of $2\pi i$ using the residue theorem after having expanded $\sin(z)$ in series

Comment: @Clayton is it correct?

Comment: Observe that $\;0, \pm\sqrt[3]{\pi}\;$ are poles of the function within $\;\gamma\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I observed... in the end I got a result of $-2\pi i$ applying the residue theorem after having substituted $w=z^3$. I had to chance the curve $\gamma'=\{w : w=\frac{8}{27}e^(i3\theta) , \theta \in [0, 2\pi) \}$ so that the index function Was $Ind(\gamma, f)=3$

Comment: @DonAntonio still i can't understand why I cant use the eexpansion I suggested... can you enlight me?

Comment: @Gitana Who said you can't? It's only you'll need **three** such Laurent expansions: one around each of the function's poles. And I cannot understand what for you did substitute...

Comment: @DonAntonio that's right! I completely forgot the other two poles in the expansion. I'll try to expand them also. I substituted because without substitution I would have had to calculate 6 residues. With my substitution I had to calculate 3 residues and they were much easier

Comment: @DonAntonio no sorry I got a different result! Can you please show me how to expand the whole thing in $z=\pi$? Also with wolfram alpha the residue in the other two poles lead me to a different result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the tree poles are simple one, we get that

$$Res_{z=0}(f)=\lim_{z\to0}\;zf(z)=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z^3}{\sin z^3}=1$$

Residue at $\;z=\pm\sqrt[3]\pi\;$:

$$Res_{z=\pm\sqrt[3]\pi}(f)=\lim_{z\to\pm\sqrt[3]\pi}\frac{(z\pm\sqrt[3]\pi)z^2}{\sin z^3}=\lim_{z\to\pm\sqrt[3]\pi}\frac{z^2+2(z\pm\sqrt[3]\pi)z}{3z^2\cos z^3}=\frac{\pi^{2/3}}{3\pi^{2/3}\cos(\pm\pi)}=\pm\frac13$$

I think the above is the easiest way to get the residues, but if you want to do Laurent series go ahead...

Comment: But since z is complex there should be other solutions I think : $z^3=k \pi$ with $k=-1, 0, 1$

Comment: @Gitana No. We know the funcion (complex or whatever) sine only vanishes on the real axis and thus the above mentioned are all the poles there are within the given curve.

Comment: thank you! Also the laurent expansion now is coherent with your result

Comment: Sorry to come back on this topic but I've thought about it again. The equation: $z^3=k \pi, k=-1,0,1$ it's solved by 7 points in the complex plane. Each one of these points though gives a result that make the sine vanish on  the real line. I think that I should check also those other points

Comment: @Gitana Of course. You have to check **all** the points that fulfill the condition you need. Only make sure those points are within the circle $\;|z|=\frac32\;$ , otherwise you're not interested in them.

Comment: Yes of course! Thank you again